# Read a file on Linux server through java program running in Windows env

Tags: java, linux, windows, eclipse

I have a simple Java program that reads a file and writes it on my console in Eclipse tool. I'm trying to execute the same Java program to read the file on a remote Linux server. How can I achieve that?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {     
public static void main(String[] args){
    String path = "C:/tmp"; 
    String file = "java2502201411.txt"; 
      try
      {
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path + "/" + file);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      String strLine; 
      while((strLine = br.readLine())!= null)
      {
       System.out.println(strLine);
      }
      }catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println(e);
      } 
   }  
}
```

I'm able to call a file from another Windows environment that is in the network. E.g: I'm trying to read a file on my Windows network such as usmnp1804 terminal.
`String path = "//usmnp1804/C$/tmp"`. Similarly, I'm trying to read a file on a Linux server but it is not working as intended, getting an error such as *File not found Exception*. I suspect such as my Java program is not able to hit the Linux server path.

`String path = "/home/jctadm/tmp".`

Comment: Is the code running on a Windows machine and trying to open a file shared from a linux cifs server?  Also: don't make a file name using `path + "/" + file`, use `new File(new File(path), file)`.

Answer (score 0):

Java can't natively open files shared across CIFS.  You have to use a client library.  [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) seems to be the de facto standard for this.  Apache [Commons Virtual File System](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) also supports this.  Both have tags here on SO: [jcifs](/questions/tagged/jcifs) and [apache-commons-vfs](/questions/tagged/apache-commons-vfs).

Answer (score 0):

This example might help, this is a basic example to use VFS to retrieve files from a remote system using the SFTP protocol. Files matching a specified regular expression are retrieved.

http://wiki.apache.org/commons/SimpleSftpFileDownload